# Symbol SDK - Get Device Serial Number

Tags: sdk, symbols

Has anyone done any development with the Symbol Device SDK? I want to get the Device Serial Number and write it to a value in the registry.

Does the Symbol SDK get you the facility of getting the Device Serial Number?  If so, do you know what the class is called as there are quite a few in the SDK pack?

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I typed your question title into google and the [first match](http://www.pocketpcdn.com/articles/serial_number.html) said

> Symbol support team wrote that Symbol PPT devices support serial number that could be read using RCM_GETUNIQUEUNITID function.

Googling for RCM_GETUNQUEUNITID then got me to [this](http://forums.devbuzz.com/fb.aspx?m=17996) which has source code to retrieve the ID.